# Rhetorische Figur: Eine Frau geht seinen Weg

Tags: rhetoric

Welches Sprachmittel ist in dem Titel dieses Buches benutzt worden?

> Eiersalat - Eine Frau geht **seinen** Weg

Comment: Helge Schneider bewegt sich nicht immer in den Grenzen der deutschen Sprache :-)

Comment: *H​u​m​o​r?* :-)

Comment: Beispiel ohne Humor (via Reg Dwight): „Angela Merkel ist der erste Bundeskanzler, der ...“

Comment: Wieso ist das jetzt ohne Humor? <duck>

Comment: ...aber das ist nicht die gleiche Situation. Bei dem Merkel-Beispiel gibt es eine Diskrepanz zwischen dem bisherigen Verständnis einer Rolle (Bundeskanzler sind männlich) und der jetzigen Situation (der aktuelle Bundeskanzler ist weiblich). Das Wort, das diese Rolle beschreibt, wird also der aktuellen Situation nicht mehr gerecht. Beim Eiersalat ist das nicht der Fall - Frauen waren schon immer weiblich und Männer männlich.

Comment: Related: [Helge Schneider - Wurstfachverkäuferin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuJT7mhCf40)

Comment: Ich glaube, die Diskrepanz über die Zeit spielt keine Rolle. Möchte man weibliche und männliche Personen ansprechen, ist die (sprachlich) korrekte Form dafür männlich. Beim Bundeskanzler ebenso wie bei Lehrern, Spielern, Journalisten. Überall. Dass man, je nach Publikum, besser auch oder sogar ausschließlich eine weibliche Form verwendet, ist ja eine andere Sache, hat aber nichts mit der Sprache zu tun. Ich zitiere dazu, wie schon im Chat: "Liebe Mitgliederinnen und Mitglieder".

Comment: @Jan: Das hat, je nach dem wie der Satz fortgesetzt wird, nichts mit einer männlichen Rolle, sondern dem generischen Maskulinum zu tun und damit, dass es keine spezifische Frauenrolle ist (Amme, Hausfrau, ...). „Angela Merkel ist der erste Bundeskanzler, der eine Frau ist.“ macht das deutlich. Oder: „Angela Merkel ist die erste dt. Bundeskanzlerin, die nach China reist.“

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Es ist eine humoristische Abhandlung über die Emanzipation der Frau von [Helge Schneider](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helge_Schneider) (der hier das Pseudonym *Helga* Schneider verwendet).

Der Gegensatz *Frau–sein* ist also eine gewollte grammatikalische Unkorrektheit. Ich weiß nicht, ob dieses Stilmittel als Oxymoron durchgeht, doch ebendieser Gegensatz soll hier ein Schmunzeln erzeugen.